# SSL wildcard certificate thumbprint

Tags: powershell, certificate

I'm trying to store the thumbprint in a variable by executing

```
$thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem -path cert:\localmachine\my | where {$_.Subject -like "*.contoso.com."}).Thumbprint
```

I seem to capture two thumbprints one for the **ssl** wildcard certificate and the client/server authentication certificate.

I only want to capture the ssl wildcard certificate

```
$thumbprint = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` character in your filter is a wildcard that is matching more than just the asterisk character. Try modifying your filter to use `-eq`. Perhaps something like the following:

```
... | where { $_.Subject -eq "CN=*.contoso.com." }
```

Or, if this is within a script you can escape the `*` with a single backtick.  If run from the command line, escape it with a double backtick. As per the documentation for [Supporting Wildcard Characters in Cmdlet Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
... | where { $_.Subject -like "``*.contoso.com." }
```

Comment: Yikes! I've been staring at the screen for too long.
Appreciated, thank you chief!